# C# DataGridView Row Coloring

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, row, cell-formatting

I'm having an issue with my `DataGridView`, where I'm using the CellFormatting method to re-color a row based on its contents. This seems to work fine in most cases, until the first row in the DGV returns true - in this case every row in the DGV is colored red.

Here's my code:

```
private void MyData_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow theRow = MyData.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        if (theRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "1")
        {
            ChangeRowColor(theRow, Color.PaleVioletRed);
        }
}

private void ChangeRowColor(DataGridViewRow r, Color c)
{
    r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = c;
}
```

Edit: Solution:

```
private void MyData_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow theRow = MyData.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        if ((int)theRow.Cells[4].Value == 1)
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting for me, i'm a newb

Comment: Adding `else { ChangeRowColor(theRow, Color.White);}` after the else if clause helps?

Comment: Can you provide your sample Data?

Comment: You can run the code above, so long as DGVColumn[4] has a value of "1" on DGVRow[0], the whole grid will be red regardless of the value, however if DGVRow[0] == "0" or any other value, only the rows which do equal "1" in Col[4] will be red as expected.

Comment: Try to add the `else` part i told you in my comment and tell me if it makes some difference

Comment: Adding that else statement kind of helped; else isn't really viable in CellFormatting because it gets fired so often it will just keep re-painting the grid. But by adding it it does only highlight on the correct rows. Though it's now only highlighting DGVColumn[5] in red for the correct rows, as opposed to the whole row.

Comment: Ok @Krisisonfire, that's what I wanted to know. Just wanted to make sure the data was correct, of course you can't use it as it would keep repainting the grid. But now i don't know what may be your issue...

Comment: I think it's relevant with your data or some piece of other code blocks that we haven't see. Because I checked your code with my data and works perfect.

Comment: Yeah,i've got working code like that too...

Comment: Maybe you are miscalculated the Index? It might be 3 and you started to count from 1 instead of 0? We can just guess from now on.

Comment: I just edited the code in the post, same issue still happening. If I add else { ChangeRowColor(theRow, Color.White);} I get the results I'm looking for but this isn't viable. This does prove that my data is correct though. I'm also looking at the debugger and can see that the data is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign the backcolor to the CellStyle in the event.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing?

Comment: In the argument e you have the property CellStyle. It's the style of of the cell and row you've got there.

Comment: You are a freaking genius and I am inferior